# Memory Management with C++ plugin plugged into C software

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Suppose I have a C-Programm that calls some code written in C++. To make it a bit more concrete, this could look similar to the following:

```
// C++:
extern "C" void * pluginFunction(void * input) {
    result = (SomeObject *) input;
    if (! result)
        SomeObject * result = new SomeObject();

    // Do something really intelligent here.
    return (void*) result;
}
```

For the calling C-programm:

```
int main() {
    void * result;
    while (something) {
        result = pluginFunction(result);
        // some more things
    }

    // Cleanup memory
}
```

Furthermore suppose that the C-Programm provides a custom memory management. Thus, the C-Programm alway knows which memory has been allocated using the provided function `custom_alloc`, `custom_free` and `custom_realloc`.

On the C++-side, the operators `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]` have been overloaded globally both in the standard and in the `throw ()` version.

Now my questions:

- If the C-part would free all memory allocated over the custom functions during the call of `pluginFunction`, would it free *all* memory actually allocated, or is there something more than the memory provided by the variants of `new`?
- What further harm would be done by bypassing the call to a proper destructor? Could that harm be avoided purly on the C++-side, e.g. within `pluginFunction`?
- Do you see any potential pitfalls or side-effects?

Please note that I have no access to the calling C-Program, but have to use the interface provided. Thus, I have no other option as to arrange my memory in a way that it gets freed properly and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is very simple: you have to destroy memory where you allocate one. So your plugin interface must provide both allocate and deallocate functions.

Comment: Honestly I can't follow your argument. Do you have sources for that rather strict claim? Reasoning where exactly the problems may arise if done otherwise?

Comment: Usually module/plugin is black box for clients, so if you have not to do any intromissions how this black box works and how it manages allocation/deallocation. For example, plugin developer decides to change implementation of the pluginFunction function and supplies new version does the following: static SomeObject object; ... return &object. How do you know that you should not deallocate the memory anymor?

Comment: Okay, that is the typical reasoning from a software design perspective. There are quite a lot of reasons why I have to cope with this, the maine one that changing the interface is no option. However, design rules for me are there to be broken if you have a reason to do so. What I'm asking about is technical limitations, thus what *can't* be done the way I describe abvoe, assuming all-knowing, faultless developers.

Comment: @AnatolyS: I think you mean "you have to destroy memory **where** you allocate it". (I'd edit, but it's less than the 6 character minimum.)

Comment: the reason is, that each module gets its own copy of the CRT, and memory must be freed by the same CRT that allocated it. See e.g.this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. C++ functions can also call malloc() or any other standard C library that might call malloc(), so overriding new and delete might not be enough. You would also need to override malloc, calloc, etc.
2. The C++ code might do some other initialization that needs deinitialization in the destructor, like opening hardware, sockets, files, etc. So yes, there can be side effects.
3. See 2.

Comment: Yep, I see both of your points. +1. Might there be anything else?